Can anyone identify this garnish?
I'm looking at an article about frisée salad, specifically at the very first picture, which is the one dish of course for which no recipe is given.

The little white flakes look so pretty, but I'm at a loss as to what they could be. Parmesan is yellowish, or is there a variety that's white like that? Or some other cheese that makes little white flakes like that? Or is this something else entirely?

Shavings can look whiter than bulk material, even with cheese, though they have to be quite thin. Combined with stretching the contrast of the photo that could be enough for parmesan or a similar cheese

Are you referring to the really small white specks like near the top of the plate, separated from the rest of the salad, or the rather large whitish things all over the middle of the salad?

As far as I can tell, all of the white stuff is identical, in other words all the same thing… Does it look different to you?

@VeryAmateur I think there are some very pale leaves as well.

You realize that this won't be so pretty when you make it at home, right? This site's style is clearly geared towards making a pleasant impression, rather than conveying information. The food photography they use is very elaborate. Somebody probably spent hours placing each leaf with tweezers, then it was photographed under perfect conditions, and then somebody else did a lot of postproduction on the picture, to turn it into a supernatural stimulus. Some of the food may even be fake props. If you make the salad, it will probably be very tasty, but not as eye-catching.

It's some kind of cheese.  Impossible to know which, without more information from the author/publisher.  Pecorino romano would be a good thing to try, or crumbled chevre.
Yes, it's very white.  However, if you look at other articles in Food and Wine with cheese on salads, you'll notice that they seem to be "whitening" cheese and other off-white ingredients in the photos.

The flakes don't look at all like crumbled cheese, chevre or something else. The closest match for the shape would be tete de moine for me. I agree that it's impossible to say for sure though, and that the whiteness isn't relevant.

You wouldn't use tete de moine on a salad, though, or break it up into such small flakes.  My first thought was salt, actually, but who would put that much salt on a salad?

Maybe it is salt flakes, for appearance in the photo and not for eating. Because it does look a bit like something drier and more translucent than cheese

So inedible and just for the photo?  I'd buy that.
